# creating css3 specific shape

Tags: html, css

[image: Desired Shape]

I trying to create the middle V section shape using css3, is this possible? This pattern is to be used as background of a footer and in a responsive layout. So I'm trying to avoid directly using image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  background color: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
```

Comment: great, what i needed. One question tho, how do you generate this so fast?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. But I highly recommend you to use images instead. But if you insist, you can refer here.

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: my main concern would be images on the position would be differ from where I want on variation of resolution